# TortiseSVN 1.7 How do you turn on modified files make their parent folder modified?

Tags: tortoisesvn

In my old version of TortiseSVN ( version 1.6) I could enable, a feature which show folders to be dirty/modified if they have subfolder or files inside them to modified.

Is this feature in TortiseSVN 1.7.5? If so How to I find it? Is it somewhere in settings?

**UPDATE**
As you can see the folder tests should be dirt/modified but its not.
[image]

**UPDATE**
Also if this helps for some reason unversioned files mark parent folder as modified is grated out.
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Settings dialog->Icon Overlays->Status Cache

Set this to `Default`, not `Shell`.

Comment: Yes! Thanks man. helped me out alot, do you know why this is?

Answer (score 0):

That is the basic feature of TortoiseSVN and is not configurable. If icon overlays are on, it will always show parent folders as dirty if the subfolders or files are modified. Only configurable item is if unversioned files should also mark parent directory as dirty.

Comment: That not happening in my current tortiseSVN repository, also list unversioned files is grayed out. Do you know why that is?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see nothing on your miniature, but here is my TortoiseSVN 1.7.6, Build 22632 - 32 Bit on XP SP3. And I change nothing from 1.6 era

[image: Icon Overlays]